# Hiding and showing divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Basically I have a settings menu with 3 options, and 3 divs, of which 2 are hidden by default. The whole thing works fine on the first click, it hides the correct div and shows the correct div, while removing the active class from the current link and adding it to the one that was clicked. However when I try clicking a different link again, it slides down the correct div, but it does not slide up the other open div. I am stuck.

Code:

html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="settingLink active" data-tab="general"><a href="#">General</a></li>
        <li class="settingLink" data-tab="social" ><a href="#">Social</a></li>
        <li class="settingLink" data-tab="captcha"><a href="#">Captcha</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The divs:

```
<div id="generalSettings">
</div>
<div id="socialSettings">
</div>
<div id="captchaSettings">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function settingMenu(event)
{
$('.settingLink').bind('click', function(){
    //The tab value of the currently clicked element
    var tab = $(this).data('tab');
    //Current active element
    var current = $('.active, .settingLink').data('tab');

    //Slide the old div up
    $('#'+current+'Settings').slideUp('fast', function(){
        //Slide the new div down
        $('#'+tab+'Settings').slideDown();
    });

    //Remove active class from current link
    $('.active, .settingLink').removeClass('active');
    //Add active class to new link
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: BTW - it's good form to hook up the click to the A-tag, not the LI.

Answer (score 2):

No comma
instead of this

```
$('.active, .settingLink')
```

try this

```
$('.active.settingLink')
```

selector

Answer (score 1):

This line if I am not mistaken .. looks like you want to store the currentCliked in current right. If it has both the classes then your selector is wrong...

```
var current = $('.active, .settingLink').data('tab');
```

should be

```
var current = $('.active.settingLink').data('tab');
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/p3PHe/)

Also its a better practice to assign the event handler instead of calling a function , because if you call a function multiple times the event handlers might be duplicated.
Attach the event to the anchor instead of li's